# What's wrong with this question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

I'm trying to find out what's wrong with [this](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/what-is-the-significance-and-history-of-using-swear-in-movies) question. But i couldn't.

https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/2448/what-is-the-significance-and-history-of-using-swear-in-movies

I don't think this question is bad enough to get 5 down votes and i'm sure it's on-topic.

I would request some moderator to shed some light on what's wrong with that question? Because that'll help me to ask the intriguing question in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initially, the question was about a specific word's first use in a movie.  Which in itself, while intriguing due to the subjet matter, is different from our other *first occurences* because asking about a *specific word* is getting to be a little *too* nit-picky as pointed out in the comments.

Secondly, part of it is from the fact that I had attempted to make it more general, using swearing in general, but as it turns out, there is actually an [exact duplicate](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1786/era-of-profanity-in-movie-scripts) of another question.

I will be merging the two shortly.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for Moderator opinions, but (since I did not downvote it myself) at least 3 non moderators have downvoted it. Really you should be asking for the opinion of the community in general.

I don't think the question is off-topic.  You must remember that upvoting and downvoting is not a measure of whether something is on topic, it is primarily a measure of how interesting or useful people think a question is.  People will also use it to suggest that something is off-topic too, but that is a secondary purpose and people with enough reputation should place a close vote if that is the case.

Honestly I think that people are just reacting to it not being that useful a question, *particularly in its initial edit*.  The question claimed that (paraphrasing) most movies use the F and S words.  This is just not true - there are many many genres of movies that have little or no swearing - the main exceptions being modern action and thriller movies.  The question then asked 'what was the first movie to use the F-Word' to which I suspect that many people will think "who cares?".

Personally I would guess the former issue (the claim about most movies having swearing) is more likely to attract down votes. People will probably not punish a question just because they are not interested in the answer.